# Why Remote Validation not Working on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have made a remote validation in my project, to avoid duplicate entries in the DB. My metadata is like this:

```
[Remote("CheckUserName", "Home", ErrorMessage = "This is a duplicate program ")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And inside my HomeController I have the function like this

```
public JsonResult CheckUserName(string UserName)
{
    if (!RUser.DupUserName(UserName))
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In my create View

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

in the repository

```
public bool DupUserName(string UserName)
{
    int q = (from a in db.Tbl_User
        where a.UserName.Equals(UserName)
        select a).Count();
    return Convert.ToBoolean(q);
}
```

Everything looks okay to me, but this validation does not work. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?
I also tried using the overload of RemoteAttribute but it doen't work.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the first line of the CheckUserName method and debug your code. this way you can find out which part of your code does not work. also, you can find your answer in the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863634/mvc-5-remote-validation

Comment: I wrote everything right but it didn't work right

Comment: I don't know what to do:(

Comment: Doesn't go to checkusername method at all

Comment: Change your method to post like the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37430821/4604881

Comment: I wrote exactly like this but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have the following settings in appSettings section of your web.config file? <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

Comment: yes i did that....:-(

Comment: every thing is ok ,I had to change the jquery version.Thankful

Comment: So your problem is solved. Thank you for sharing your solution. Good luck.